# Multiple-select with Listjs libraries not working on live server

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, multiple-select, listjs

I'm giving a walk by here because I'm trying implement a library named Multiple-Select with Listjs in a Wordpress theme to filter options availables. The interesting here is that, in my local it works perfectly in a single dropdown, you can see it work here: http://dcc04716.ngrok.io/property

But when I load it to staging server it doesn't work like a single select/dropdown (as local). The only way that it works is making it a multiple select/dropdown and I don't want that: http://lri.clientdemos.net/property/

So, I have been checking what can be happening but no idea.

Can I convert the multiselect in a single or something?

Please, I share my code (for quick test purpose, I am loading the libraries in the file not with the `wp_enqueue_script` way):

https://gist.github.com/jmanzo/35d10e9a1403bbe89d0891fe3755324a

Comment: You're getting 404 errors from your resources, which obviously doesn't help. Have you looked into FacetWP?

Comment: That 404 errors I got it in local as well. But still in local works but on staging site no

Comment: How is it working when it says "multipleselect is not a function"?

Answer (score 0):

You are facing the issue on the staging server because the multi-select js file path is wrong. I have attached the screenshot for your reference.

[image]

[image]